# How can I reconfigure my cluster's kubelets with kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am currently trying to find a way to reconfigure the evicition thresholds of all of my clusters kubelets. The cluster has been initialized with `kubeadm init` and the worker nodes have been added with `kubeadmin join`.

Now kubeadm has correctly written the kubelet configuration to the `kubelet-config-1.16` configmap in the `kube-system` namespace and I can see the settings there.

However, what I gather from the documentation, updating it in that configmap will not adjust it for the existing kubelets.

Could someone point me to the right resources?

Thank you!

Comment: there's probably a better way, but as an ugly workaround you can basically delete each node, run `kubeadm reset` on it and then `kubeadm join` again: if you do it 1 by 1, then just 1 node down for a few minutes should not affect stability of your cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new ConfigMap from the old ConfigMap and modify it to have desired configuration for eviction threshold and then edit the node’s reference to point to the new ConfigMap with the following command:

```
kubectl edit node ${NODE_NAME}
```

In your text editor, add the following YAML under spec:

```
configSource:
    configMap:
        name: CONFIG_MAP_NAME # replace CONFIG_MAP_NAME with the name of the ConfigMap
        namespace: kube-system
        kubeletConfigKey: kubelet
```

This process is well documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Will this survive upgrades via kubeadm?